# Shopware 6: how to delete all products via admin api

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-api

How to **delete all products** via `admin api`?

To achieve the goal i try to use the [Bulk Payloads | Deleting entities](https://shopware.stoplight.io/docs/admin-api/ZG9jOjEyMzA4NTUx-bulk-payloads#deleting-entities)

The doc says:

> [...] To delete entities, the payload of an operation contains the IDs. [...]

Questions:

- to delete all products i have to read first all `product.id`'s?
- ***or*** is there a alternative way with a type of "wildcard"?

My current request body (using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/)) ...:

```
{
    "delete-product": {
        "entity": "product",
        "action": "delete",
        "payload": []
    }
}
```

... response with (products remains in db):

```
{
    "extensions": [],
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "delete-product": {
            "extensions": [],
            "result": []
        }
    },
    "deleted": [],
    "notFound": []
}
```

**EDIT #1**
With `id`'s provided...:

```
...
const obj = {
    "delete-products": {
        "entity": "product",
        "action": "delete",
        "payload": [
            {"id": "73af65014974440b95450f471b3afed8"},
            {"id": "784f25a29e034fad9a416923f964ba8a"}
        ]
    }
}
apiClient.request({
    "url": "/_action/sync",
    "method": "POST",
    obj
})
...
```

... the request fails in class `Symfony\\Component\\Serializer\\Encoder\\JsonDecode`  with message:

> detail: "Syntax error"

Debugging the request, **payload is missing** (empty content):

- What is wrong with the configuration of the `/api/_action/sync` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - to delete all products i have to read first all product.id's?

Yes, that is what you'll have to do. This is necessary to maintain the extendibility of the platform. The core or other plugins may react to the deletion of products by subscribing to an entity lifecycle event. This event includes the id of the deleted entity. Hence why it is necessary to explicitly provide the ids  of the entities in the first place.

Comment: thx (again) for answered. Please take a look of my **EDIT #1**, mybe you can provide a solution.

Comment: @rammi22 I believe it should be a new question as it's it will require more details from you & I believe it's unrelated to the original question at hand

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, what it means is that you will need a low impacting query to get all product id's, store it into a variable & delete them. Use `includes:["id"]` filter to just get the ID's.

Here is an example of me deleting some products in Postman.
Request body:

```json
{
    "delete-product": {
        "entity": "product",
        "action": "delete",
        "payload": {{gen_dynamic_products}}
    }
}
```

Pre-request script (you'll need to adjust this sightly to get your ID's):

```js
const map = new Array(30).fill(0).map((val, index) => {
    return { id: pm.environment.get('gen_product_list_sub_' + index) };
});
pm.variables.set('gen_dynamic_products', JSON.stringify(map));
```

Comment: FYI, the code concerning fetching the parent ids really has nothing to do with the process of deleting. This is only done to enrich the results of an operation with possible parents of an entity, since they may have to be re-indexed after write operations to their children.

Comment: Adjusted answer to leave the Postman specific ID provider logic